# Deny EXECUTE function but allow select from tables

Tags: postgresql

On postgresql 11, I have a function and a table in a non-public schema. I would like to create a new user that can only select from the table but not execute the function.

I tighten up security on public schema by running the following (should not be related to my problem, but just in case):

```
REVOKE ALL ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL ON DATABASE my_db FROM PUBLIC;
```

I created a user like this:

```
CREATE ROLE my_user NOSUPERUSER NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE NOINHERIT LOGIN PASSWORD 'my_password' VALID UNTIL 'infinity';
```

Then:

```
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE my_db TO my_user;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA my_schema TO my_user;
GRANT SELECT ON my_schema.my_table TO my_user;
REVOKE ALL ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA my_schema FROM my_user;
```

The user is still able to execute the function.
If I revoke the USAGE permission on schema, then user loses ability to execute the function, but then it is also unable to select from the table.

Comment: Can you show how the function is defined, please?

Comment: Maybe "*The `FUNCTION` syntax works for plain functions, aggregate functions, and window functions, but not for procedures; use `PROCEDURE` for those. Alternatively, use `ROUTINE` to refer to a function, aggregate function, window function, or procedure regardless of its precise type.*" has something to do with it.

Comment: The function is indeed a function (with a return value) so it's not a procedure. Thank you for the info though as I wasn't aware of this new procedure feature. Learned something new!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my_user has access to the schema, and PUBLIC has access to the function (or at least you haven't shown a revocation of it).  Put them together, and my_user can access the function.  Revoke from PUBLIC as well as my_user.

In PostgreSQL, `PUBLIC` has the `EXECUTE` privilege on functions by default.

To prevent functions created in the future from getting EXECUTE granted to PUBLIC automatically, you would need:

```
alter default privileges revoke all on functions from public;
```

You would need to execute this once for each user who will be creating functions.

Comment: Great! Thank you this did the trick: `REVOKE ALL ON ALL ROUTINES IN SCHEMA my_schema FROM PUBLIC;` I was quite surprised by this as I thought the PUBLIC role only gives access to objects in the public schema.

Comment: My intent is to limit this user to one table only and nothing else (including future objects), have I missed other REVOKEs? What's the correct commands to create such a user?

Comment: I've added alter default priv example.